Problem with example, On the Ultimate Instability of the Aloha Protocol, from Sheldon Ross' book
I'm having some difficulty understanding this example. It's given in Sheldon Ross' book, Introduction to Probability Models (13th edition), on page 221, example 4.21.
Example 4.21. (On the Ultimate Instability of the Aloha Protocol). Consider a communications facility in which the numbers of messages arriving during each of the time periods $n=1,.2
\ldots$ are independent and identically distributed random variables. Let $a_1 = P\{i \text{ arrivals}\}$, and suppose that $a_0 + a_1 < 1$. Each arriving message will transmit at the end of the period in which it arrives. If exactly one message is transmitted, then the transmission is successful and the message leaves the system. However, if at any time two or more messages simultaneously transmit, then a collision is deemed to occur and these messages remain in the system. Once a message is involved in a collision it will, independently of all else, transmit at the end of each additional period with probability $p$—the so-called Aloha protocol (because it was first instituted at the University of Hawaii). We will show that such a system is asymptotically unstable in the sense that the number of successful transmissions will, with probability $1$, be finite.
We define $X_n$ to be the number of messages in the system at the beginning of the $n$th period. Then, $X_n$ is a Markov chain with state space $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$. For $k\geq 0$, we define indicator variables $I_k = 1$, if the first time the chain departs state $k$ it directly goes to state $(k-1)$; and $0$ otherwise. Here, we also set $I_k = 0$ if the chain is never in state $k$.
Now,
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}(\sum_{k\geq0})I_k &= \sum_{k\geq 0}E(I_k) \\&= \sum_{k\geq 0} P(I_k = 1) \\&\leq \sum_{k\geq 0} P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is ever visited}) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Q$1$. Does $(1)$ follow because of this?
\begin{align*}
    P(I_k = 1) &= P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is ever visited})P(k \text{ is ever visited}) + P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is never visited})P(k \text{ is never visited}) \\&= P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is ever visited})P(k \text{ is ever visited}) \hspace{20pt}\{\text{because, } P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is never visited}) = 0\} \\&\leq P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is ever visited}) \hspace{20pt}\{\text{because, } 0\leq P(k \text{ is ever visited}) \leq 1\}
\end{align*}
Next, the author says, $P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is ever visited})$ is the probability that when state $k$ is departed, the next state is $(k - 1)$. That is, it is the conditional probability that a transition from $k$ to $(k - 1)$ given that that it is not back into $k$, and so
\begin{align*}P(I_k = 1\mid k \text{ is ever visited}) = \frac{P_{k, (k-1)}}{1-P_{k,k}} \tag{2}\end{align*}
Here, $P_{ij} = P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} =i)$ are the transition probabilities of the Markov chain.
Q$2$. I don't undetsand how $(2)$ follows. I also don't understand how $P(I_k = 1 \mid k \text{ is ever visited})$ is equal to the aforementioned conditional probability "a transition from $k$ to $(k - 1)$ given that that it is not back into $k$".
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I'm also attaching screenshot of the solution below.


